# Custom TextView pass data to onDraw

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

I need to do custom TextView (text with border effect). I have something code like below.

```
public class BorderTextView extends TextView {

    private int textSize;
    private String strokeColor;
    private String textColor;
    private String text;
    private Canvas canvas;

    public BorderTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public String getMyStrokeColor() {
        return strokeColor;
    }

    public String getMyTextColor() {
        return textColor;
    }

    public String getMyText() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getMyTextSize() {
        return textSize;
    }

    public void setParameters(String strokeColor, String textColor, String text, int textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.text = text;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

         if (getMyStrokeColor() != null) {
           Paint paint = new Paint();
           paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(getMyStrokeColor()));
           paint.setTextSize(getMyTextSize());
           paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
           paint.setStrokeWidth(getTextSize() / 5);
           paint.setAntiAlias(true);
           paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

           int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
           int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() +
           paint.ascent()) / 2));

           canvas.drawText(getMyText(), xPos, yPos, paint);

           paint.setStrokeWidth(0f);
           paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(getMyTextColor()));
           paint.setTextSize(getMyTextSize());

           canvas.drawText(getMyText(), xPos, yPos, paint);
         }
    }

}
```

In XML:

```
                <com.app.widget.BorderTextView
                    android:id="@+id/category"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center" />
```

And in activity:

```
private BorderTextView category;
category = (BorderTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.category);

category = new BorderTextView(getActivity(), null);
category.setParameters("#000000", firstColor, secondColor, 60);
```

How can I pass these 4 values to my custom textview? Because my code above doesn't work.

It doesn't work, because my values are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're initializing `category` to the `BorderTextView` defined in the layout, but then you're instantiating a new instance of `BorderTextView` and assigning it to `category`. The instance you're calling `setParameters()` on is not the on-screen instance, and is therefore not the instance being drawn. Remove the line:

```
category = new BorderTextView(getActivity(), null);
```

Comment: Mike, thank you soo much! I expected it, but i wasn't sure. Big thanks to you!